# PayPal Express Checkout and currency conversion?

Tags: c#, paypal, currency

I need some information about PayPal's Express Checkout (in C#). I have that payment method implemented already.

The PayPal Seller's account main currency is AUD. In my project, where that payment method is related to, every price is also displayed in AUD. And here's the thing - the project has also the Polish language implemented, where all prices is being shown in PLN currency (the price is being calculated basing on the Polish National Bank exchange rate).

The problem is, that if we have a price, e.g. 3 AUD, in my system it is calculated to e.g. 6.30 PLN but the PayPal is price is e.g. 6.59 PLN (I mean, it's different). So, is there any possibility to know how to calculate the price in the PayPal's way ?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has a [ConvertCurreny API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/) that allows you to get the conversion.  Use the ConvertCurrency API operation to request the current foreign exchange (FX) rate for a specific amount and currency.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted their customer service and they explained, that at least in my region, they added 3.5% over the XE.com exchange rates. I was able to hand this to my accountant and use it as evidence of a tax-deductible business expense.